# Changing Widget type to 'Unique Values' and making it editable using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, widget, unique-value

I'm new to the QGIS software and am attempting to change the widget type to *'Unique Value'* (by default, it's 'Text Edit') using PyQGIS.

[image: Unique Value-Editable]

I have more than 20 fields in a layer for which I want to set the Widget Type as **Unique Values** and make them **Editable**. However, manually setting this up is taking too much time. I've tried the following code:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsEditorWidgetSetup

layer = iface.activeLayer()
field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName('POINT_ADDR, STEET_ROAD, LANDMARK')

if field_index != -1:
    layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(field_index, QgsEditorWidgetSetup('Unique Values', {}))
    layer.startEditing()   
    layer.commitChanges()
else:
    print("Field 'Your Field Name' does not exist in the layer.")
```

After running this code QGIS will crash and will close.

*Are there any alternative ways to overcome this problem?*

Comment: You can only get the index of one field at a time with `indexFromName()` method. You will have to loop through the fields one by one. Also, you need to `startEditing()` before making changes, and then `commitChanges()` afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance It resolved the issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# start with a list of your fields to edit
mt20_fields = ['POINT_ADDR', 'STEET_ROAD', 'LANDMARK']

# fields must be iterated through:
for field in mt20_fields:
    field_index = layer.fields().indexFromName(field)
    if field_index == -1:
        # if field does not exist, skip to the next one
        print(f"field {field} not found")
        continue
    # otherwise, set widget settings to type='UniqueValues' and config={'Editable':True}
    layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(field_index, QgsEditorWidgetSetup('UniqueValues', {'Editable':True}))
```

Note that 'UniqueValues' needs to be one word. And there is no need to enable editing or commit changes on the layer.